SOQL error on Same-Name Fields in 2nd-Generation Package
I have a 2nd-generation package that includes an Apex Class which is able to read from custom fields inside the org it's installed in. I have multiple packages using the same namespace, let's call it MyNamespace.
In one package, core, I have a field on Account called MyNamespace__Primary_Contact__c.
In another package, extension, there is an Apex Class/Visualforce Page that needs to see and display both custom and packaged fields.
I've installed core and extension in an org, and that org has a Custom field on Account called Primary_Contact__c.
When I run this page and it queries both fields, I get the error:
duplicate field selected: MyNamespace__Primary_Contact__c

When I look at the SOQL query that's generated/run by the code, the SELECT statement has both fields, with the namespace on only one of them. Primary_Contact__c doesn't show up anywhere else in the query.
Primary_Contact__c, 
MyNamespace__Primary_Contact__c, 

If I ran this query in dev console, it works just fine. If I ran this query in custom Apex, it would work just fine. So why doesn't it when the code is in a managed package?
Being the code is running under a namespaced context, is there a way to access the explicitly non-namespaced field?

Salesforce automatically assumes that all non-namespaced custom references in a Managed Package with a Namespace needs to be prefixed. This behavior is beneficial in the usual sense, because a developer can deploy the same source code to a non-namespaced environment (e.g. generic Developer Edition org) and a packaging org (or for Second-Generation Managed Packaging), without maintaining two different sets of source code. This behavior applies to virtually everything, from describes, to dynamic SOQL calls, Apex Code, and more.
This is why your queries in the Developer Console, or even in Execute Anonymous scripts, don't have this problem. They're not running in the context of the managed package. If you were to set the Call Options Header to use a specific namespace, you'd run into the same limitations in the Developer Console or any other tool, such as the Salesforce Workbench. The context you're working in matters.
Unfortunately, code that lives inside the Managed Package is doomed to its limitations. It cannot see any field or object that has the same name as a namespace-bearing component in your package. It can see fields and objects from other namespaces just fine, but will not be able to see those components that have been shadowed by any Managed Package components of the same name.
Solutions to this problem are to either use a different namespace for the package that needs access to those fields or objects, or provide an Unlocked Package or unpackaged components that do not reside in the namespace. You may need to provide global methods or classes inside your Managed Package to allow interfacing with protected components in the Managed Package.

We had this problem with quite a few of our customers, so we ended up prefixing fields to minimize the chance of this happening.  e.g. instead of Primary_Contact__c, we'd use x_Primary_Contact__c

The above comment describes an additional solution - rename the subscriber custom field API name. This is what our customers do when they hit this problem.
